# jQuery FullCalendar onclick show popup

Tags: jquery, calendar

Here is my jQuery Fullcalendar script which shows calendar in grid view. Now onClick of event i want to show details in popup instead of opening in browser, i tried many callbacks but didn't work. Has anyone worked on it before ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        // US Holidays
        // events: 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic',


        eventClick: function(event) {
            // opens events in a popup window
            window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
            return false;
        },

        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) {
                $('#loading').show();
            }else{
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        }

    });

});
```

Tried below thing but didn't work

```
eventClick: function(event) {
            if (event.url) {
              $('#myDialog')
                .load(event.url)
                .dialog({
                  width: 500,
                  height:300
                });
              return false;
        }},
```

Comment: So it currently works, it just opens in a window instead of a popup?

Comment: Yes it is working but opening up link in new window. I was looking for something like to open in alert dialog or popup.

Answer (score 2):

If by

> show details in popup

you mean an alert, you could do this:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
    // change the border color just for fun
    $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
}
```

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/vegemite4me/N8XT9/

Comment: Thanks vegemite4me. I tried the same from their documentation link, but it doesn't work

Comment: @user574639 Does my example in JSFiddle work for you? It does for me.

Comment: Yes I tried this as well. It shows red color border but again it opens up into tab in browser

Comment: I am trying this on Android. So does it has anything to do specifically with android structure ?

Comment: @user574639 Get it to work in Chrome or Firefox before trying it on an Android.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

HTML

```
<div id="popup"></div>
```

CSS

```
#popup {
    display: none;
}
```

JQuery

```
eventClick: function(event) {
    // opens events in a popup window
    $('#popup').html('<iframe src="'+event.url+'" width="700" height="600"></iframe>');
    $('#popup').dialog({autoOpen: false, modal: true, width: 750, height: 675});
    return false;
},
```

Note: Make sure you download and include JQuery UI [from here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) if you haven't.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5XvJr/)

Comment: Thanks Chad, i tried but still it opens in new browser window and not in dialog box.

Comment: I am trying this on Android. So does it has anything to do specifically with android structure ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use eventClick for fullcalendar like below

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
// call your javascript function to open modal or popup here
alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
alert('View: ' + view.name);

// change the border color just for fun
$(this).css('border-color', 'red');

 }
});
```

the document link is [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick).